# Two balls are chosen without replacement from three sacks containing 6 balls each. Find probability to pick second ball from same sack as first one?

Tags: probability

My answer is $\dfrac{1}{3}$ because I guess the number of balls in the sack does not matter. However, the answer stated in the resource from where I have taken this question is different. They do consider the number of balls in all the sacks.

Comment: @AlvinL even then I guess the probability of choosing a ball from the same bag on second attempt will be 1/3.

Comment: As indicated by the answer of SmolStrawberry, the question, as stated is ambiguous.  It depends on the method used to select a ball on each turn.  If, on each turn, you select a bag at random, and then select a ball (at random) from the selected bag, then your answer of $~\color{red}{(1/3) ~\text{is correct}}.$  If instead, on the second turn, each of the $17$ remaining balls ($\color{red}{\text{somehow}}$) has an equally likely chance of being drawn, then the answer is $~\dfrac{5}{17}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that choosing a bag is random then it would make sense that it would 1/3.

But with the answer you got, I guess you could consider you had 3 sacks with balls, assume 3 different colors and now you pool it into one bag

Then it should be easy to see that picking a ball of the same "color" would be 5/17 where 17 is remaining amount of balls and 5 is the rest of the balls with the same "color"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed strange. It assumes that balls are selected with equal probability, independent of the ball's sack. The problem's author seems did not thought at all how sacks are selected. The others proposed to replace sacks by colors. This makes the problem clear because now you need not select a sack and there is no problem with equiprobable selection of balls. You may also think that all three sacks are emptied into the common sack before ball's selection, to make ball's selection equiprobable. So don't overthink, just use the standard approach for similar problems.

As usual, to get answer the number of ways to select 2 balls from the same sack should be divided by the number of ways to select 2 balls from the all sacks. Surely it depends on the number of balls in a sack.

The first number is $$3\cdot \binom62$$
The second number is $$\binom{3\cdot 6}{2}$$